# Why is this a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program for a class that is supposed to be a doubly linked list. It compiles but when I try to do the command addleft or addright, I get a segmentation fault error. I'm fairly new to C++, so any suggestions would be great. I posted the relevant portion of the code.

List header file:

```
//list.h

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class List {
    friend class Node;
public:
    List();
    void addleft(int);
    void addright(int);
    int left();
    int right();
    void print();
    bool search(int);
    //Node *head;
    //Node *tail;
    //Node *n;
};
```

List class file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "List.h"
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;
Node *current;
Node *tail;
Node *head;
Node *n;

List::List() {

}

void List::addleft(int a) {
    n = new Node;                                                       //The pointer n points to a new Node
    n->number = a;                                                      //Set the value in the node
    n->next = head;                                                     //Point the node to the old head of the linked list
    head->prev = n;                                                     //Link the old head node to the new node
    head = n;                                                           //Set the new node as the new head of the linked list
    head->prev = NULL;                                                  //Make the new node's previous pointer point to nothing (NULL)
    if(current == NULL) {                                               //If the list is empty...
            current = n;                                                //Set the new node as the current node pointer
        }
}

void List::addright(int a) {
    n = new Node;                                                       //The pointer n points to a new Node
    n->number = a;                                                      //Set the value in the node
    n->prev = tail;                                                     //Point the node to the old head of the linked list
    tail->next = n;                                                     //Link the old tail node to the new node
    tail = n;                                                           //Set the new node as the new tail of the linked list
    tail->next = NULL;                                                  //Make the new node's next pointer point to nothing (NULL)
    if(current == NULL) {                                               //If the list is empty...
        current = n;                                                    //Set the new node as the current node pointer
    }
}

int List::left() {
    current = current->prev;
    return current->number;
}

int List::right() {
    current = current->next;
    return current->number;
}

void List::print() {

}

bool List::search(int a) {
    int search;
    //while(search != tail) {

    //}
}
```

Node header file:

```
//node.h

using namespace std;

class Node {
    friend class List;
public:
    Node();
private:
    int number;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};
```

Node class file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "List.h"
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

Node::Node() {
    next = NULL;
    prev = NULL;
}
```

Comment: show me the struct node. I suggest you'd better draw a picture to simulate the data structure. Be care of every pointer!

Comment: ` I posted the relevant portion of the code.` No you didn't. The declaration of Node is needed too.

Comment: Also you forgot to delete the new Node.

Comment: And throw in `List` while you're at it, including specifically the constructor.

Comment: I suggest that you run this code, with a test harness app, under a debugger.  Single-step and watch carefully the program flow and all the var values.  Yes, this is hard work but, to become a competent developer, you MUST be able to debug stuff like this on your own:)

Comment: `head->prev = n; head = n; head->prev = NULL;` This sequence of operations looks very strange. You are assigning a value to `->prev`, and then dropping it right away

Comment: @GiulioFranco its correct (provided `head` isn't null or indeterminate, which I believe is the real error, but without the constructor we've no way of knowing). Think about what `head-prev` points to *after* `head = n`.

Comment: @Giulio Franco: Note that the value of `head` changes between the assignments to `head->prev`. So, there's nothing really strange here.

Comment: So that's the definition and the constructor? Well you can confirm the null-pointer dereferences now, since you're globals are initialized to said-value on startup.

Comment: You mean head tail and current were not initialized at all? If so this is would most likely crash on the first usage of any of these.

Comment: I edited the question to add all of the code, other than the main file which just handles I/O.

Comment: @drescherjm they're initialized. they have static storage duration, so they're zero-initialized, and per C++11 8.5p5 (footnote 103), that means as pointers they're initialized to `nullptr`. But the null-dereference is still just as bad.

Comment: head, tail and current should all be members of your list class and they should all be initialized to NULL in the constructor for List. However after you fix that you need to check for NULL before you try to use these.

Comment: @drescherjm So like List::List() {
    current = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    head = NULL;
}

Comment: @user2954645 They **should** be private members of `List`, and should be placed on an initialization list, `List::List() : head(), tail(), current() {}`

Comment: That is what I would have done given this assignment. It's been over a decade since I implemented a list myself.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the `head` and `tail` are initially initialized to null pointers. This is why the very first attempt to add anything crashes. If that is the case, you have to handle the very first addition by a special branch of the code. That special branch has to be written specifically for the situation when both `head` and `tail` are null.

**EDIT:** After seeing more of the code we can conclude that this is indeed the case with your code.

However, writing a `List` class and then declaring `head` and `tail` as file-scope variables (instead of making them members of `List` class) makes no sense whatsoever. It looks like you originally declared them as class members, but later commented these members out. Why???

Comment: I won't downvote it, but this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Giulio Franco: I'm pretty sure that the part about null pointers *is* the answer. Which is why I posted it as an answer.

Comment: +1 ... and is why I up-voted it.

Comment: That's why I did not downvote it.

Comment: @WhozCraig it may be but I have seen people be very wrong when the answer looked obvious as well.

Comment: I commented them out of the class because when it was like that I was getting an error "error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope"
When I declared them separately, it compiled.

Comment: @user2954645: I don't see any reason for " ‘head’ was not declared in this scope" error. In any case, if you were getting that error, you should have addressed it directly, instead of sweeping it under the carpet by redeclaring the variables as globals.